# iptables: why are outgoing connections working even though no rules allow it

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, raspbian

The INPUT and OUTPUT chain policies are set to DROP. Very few rules allowing only specific traffic between directly cable-connected devices. However, if I temporarily add a cable that goes to the router, why can I initiate outgoing connections and receive answers, like do `apt update`, even though there are no rules allowing HTTP traffic in our out?

I have noticed that if I add `iptables -P FORWARD DROP` then those outgoing connections don't work anymore. Why does the FORWARD chain have any impact in this?

```
raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 332 packets, 244K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1254 79084 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       66.66.66.5           66.66.66.3           tcp dpt:21385 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
 1453 2495K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 373 packets, 47731 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1715  162K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       99.99.99.3           99.99.99.2           tcp dpt:5656
    6   456 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       99.99.99.3           99.99.99.2           udp dpt:123
  952  156K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Secondary question: Is there any risk in using those easy to recognize IP addresses between my internally and directly cable-connected devices? Could packets leak, because those are valid public addresses?

EDIT: adding requested info.

[image: network diagram]

We are talking about the device "Raspi Client".

Output of `iptables-save`:

```
raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Jan 19 10:42:58 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [529:48304]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:420]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2465:187164]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2804:242065]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 19 10:42:58 2022
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Jan 19 10:42:58 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [607:267621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [394:50896]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 66.66.66.5/32 -d 66.66.66.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21385 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 99.99.99.3/32 -d 99.99.99.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5656 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 99.99.99.3/32 -d 99.99.99.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 19 10:42:58 2022
```

Comment: Please add output of `iptables-save` to the question, and a network diagram.

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains cover for communication where the source or destination of the traffic is the router itself.

`FORWARD` covers the traffic that the router forwards from one interface to another (from LAN port to WAN port and vice versa.

Comment: But they both use `ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED`, so `NEW` connections should no be allowed.

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was completely wrong. I have replaced the answer.

Comment: But the device that has these rules (it has the IPs `99.99.99.3` and `66.66.66.3`) is not supposed to do any routing. And it doesn't. Therefore I thought the `FORWARD` chain is irrelevant for my use.


If I add another cable that connects to the internet, and gives the device another IP through DHCP that is not explicitly allowed in the rules, why can it even start a connection to the internet? In my mind, the device itself contacting an internet server is `OUTPUT` and not `FORWARD`? 


Several docs seem to confirm this.

Comment: Then it must be something else in your network that causes this, I have asked for more information.

Comment: I have added the info you requested. Thanks for trying to help!